# laravel 4 insert data and if user has file directly update data

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have following code

```
$produk = Produk::create(array(
  'nama_produk'     => $nama_produk,
  'deskripsi'           => $deskripsi
));
$id_produk = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
```

when user has file (image) too i want to  update last insert data

```
if (Input::hasFile('produk_image')) {
    $file                   = Input::file('produk_image');
    $destinationPath        = "img/produk/";
    $destinationPathThumb   = "img/produk/thumb/";

    //display thumb for list admin
    $fileName               = $file[0]->getClientOriginalName();
    $display_thumb          = $destinationPathThumb.'thumb-'.$fileName;
    $produk = Produk::where('id_produk', "=", $id_produk)->get();
    $produk->thumbImage     = $pathThumb
    $produk->save();
}
```

when i used `get()` i got this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()
```

if i used `first()` i got error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `produk` set `nama_produk` = produk1, `deskripsi` = deskripsiproduk1, `updated_at` = 2015-06-24 03:02:19 where `id` is null)
```

i really sure my script already found last insert data
when i use `count()` and `return $produk`
i got result **1**

but somehow when i try to change script from

```
$produk = Produk::where('id_produk', "=", $id_produk)->get();
```

to become insert new produk like this

```
$produk = new Produk;
```

it's running well
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model in Laravel need to have field id as the primary key.

If you use another field name, you need to override properties of Model with primaryKey property.

In your case (if id_produk is your primary key) then you need to add this into your Produk class :

protected $primaryKey = 'id_produk';